# Generate text file from Google Spreadsheet and return its link to a cell in the sppreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I have some strings as data that I am originally storing in a cell, say D2. I want to store that data onto a text file or Google docs file and then print the link to that file in D2. How do I achieve that? The code I am using generates a list of names having a certain grade. When I return the object, the cell is empty and the file is also not downloaded. What is the issue?

```
function getList(grade) {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var list = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length ; i++ ) {
        var sheet = sheets[i];
        for(var j = 2; j <= 100; j++) { 
            var key = sheet.getRange("G"+j.toString()).getValue();
            var val = sheet.getRange("B"+j.toString()).getValue();
            if (key == grade) {
                list += val;
                list += '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    var output = ContentService.createTextOutput(list);
    output.downloadAsFile('names.txt');
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Please share your research and code here then only we will be able to help you

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi i have added the code that i am using.

Comment: This is not even close to what you want, please digg deeper in the documentation and in this site and tag.

Comment: I want to store the list generated by the function into a text file, and provide its link in the google spreadsheet.

Comment: I tried downloadAsFile() but no effect.